# I have trouble with clearing my console in C#

Tags: c#, console

I have trouble with clearing my console with method:

```
Console.Clear();
```

Apparently it clears only the visible part of console. When i scroll up the earlier text is still there not deleted.

i tried to give it time to clear so i put the:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

before and after the `Clear` method but it doesn't work

```
    internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for(int i =0; i<100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
        Console.Clear();
        while(Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Spacebar) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which operating system? Which console (e.g. on Windows: conhost or Windows Terminal)?

Comment: Windows and i think that is WIndows Console Host. But i dont know for sure. When i created project in Visual Studio i chose Console Application

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me. I think you'll have to post your code.

Comment: Couldn't post the original code because it's to big but I made replacment code in which i have the same problem